# can't figure out why yacc/bison grammar doesn't work

Tags: bison, yacc

This is not homework, though it is from a book.

I'm given a yacc/bison spec file. The task is to add a new production

```
number -> number digit
digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

to calculate the value of a number and do away with a `NUMBER` token. The grammar is provided below.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int yylex();
int yyerror();
%}

%token NUMBER

%%

command : exp { printf("%d\n", $1); }
        ; /* allows printing of the result */

exp : exp '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | exp '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | term { $$ = $1; }
    ;

term : term '*' factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
     | factor { $$ = $1; }
     ;

factor : NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
       | '(' exp ')' { $$ = $2; }
       ;

%%

int main() {
  return yyparse();
}

int yylex() {
  int c;
  while((c = getchar()) == ' ');
  /* eliminate blanks*/
  if (isdigit(c)) {
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    scanf("%d", &yylval);
    return (NUMBER);
  }
  if (c == '\n') return 0;
  /* makes the parse stop */
  return (c);
}

int yyerror(char * s) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
  return 0;
} /* allows for printing of an error message */
```

As an experiment to make sure that I'm doing everything correctly I eliminated the number token, added the following production:

```
number : '1' {$$ = $1;}
```

changed the `factor` production to

```
factor : number {$$ = $1;}
```

and eliminated

```
if (isdigit(c)) {
  ungetc(c, stdin);
  scanf("%d", &yylval);
  return (NUMBER);
}
```

from the `yylex()` function. In other words the spec file looks like the following:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int yylex();
int yyerror();
%}


%%

command : exp { printf("%d\n", $1); }
        ; /* allows printing of the result */

exp : exp '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | exp '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | term { $$ = $1; }
    ;

term : term '*' factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
     | factor { $$ = $1; }
     ;

factor : number { $$ = $1; }
       | '(' exp ')' { $$ = $2; }
       ;

number : '1' { $$ = $1; }
       ;

%%

int main() {
  return yyparse();
}

int yylex() {
  int c;
  while((c = getchar()) == ' ');
  /* eliminate blanks*/

  if (c == '\n') return 0;
  /* makes the parse stop */
  return (c);
}

int yyerror(char * s) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
  return 0;
} /* allows for printing of an error message */
```

However after I run the code on the following expression: 1+1, I get an answer of 0.

Come someone help me out? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: oh no, i got downgraded by 1 vote. why is this question wrong?

Comment: Probably because debugging questions are off-topic here. You're looking for StackOverflow.

Comment: @lxrec I see. i was afraid that if I ask it on overflow they'll tell me to move it here. I had hat happen to me.

Comment: @lxrec It is my understanding that it is possible to move questions between stack exchange websites, but one needs enough "points" to do so. I don't have them. Do you mind moving the question for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
number : '1' { $$ = $1; }
```

This says that the parser can reduce the terminal `'1'` (a single character token) to a `number` and that when it does so, it should copy the semantic value.

Very good. But what is the semantic value of '`1`'? As with any other token, it is the value stored into `yylval` by  `yylex` when it returns the token type. In the original code, for example, `yylex` used `scanf("%d", &yylval)` to set the semantic value of the `NUMBER` token. But in the new code, `yylex` isn't living up to its contract. It never sets `yylval` to anything, so the semantic value of any token it returns is undefined. (That's perfectly OK as long as the parser never uses the semantic value of the token. `'+'` isn't given a semantic value either, but the parser isn't expecting one.)

In the case of the token `'1'`, the parser really doesn't need the scanner's assistance: it's clear what the semantic value should be:

```
number : '1' { $$ = 1; }
```

Alternatively, the scanner could help out:

```
if (isdigit(c)) yylval = c - '0';
return c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Another question. Say a number production is defined as `number : '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | 9' `. How would I extract semantic value in this case without the use of `if (isidgit(c))`? is it even possible?

Comment: @flashburn: in yacc/bison, you cannot attach a single action to more than one production, so you would need ten actions in that case. That should give you a good clue as to the solution :) (And of course by the time the parser sees one of those terminals, it has no need to call isdigit.)

Comment: What I'm not clear about is where the recognized value is stored? I'm having difficulty understanding the meaning of `$$`, `$1`, `$2` and their relationship to `yylval` as well as to the `%union`. I would really appreciate help on this. Maybe we could create a new topic on this to avoid discussion in the comments.

Comment: [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Semantic-Values.html). They are stored on the parser stack, alongside the token itself and the parser state (and the source location, if that feature is enabled). `%union` defines the semantic value datatypes. `yylval` is the mechanism by which the semantic value of a newly scanned terminal is communicated to the parser; it's pushed onto the stack when the token is shifted. `$$` is the semantic value of the production, which you compute in the semantic action. `$n` are the semantic values of the RHS components (on the stack).

Comment: ... and don't overthink the problem. It's actually all very simple and there is no magic involved. `%union` is as close to magic as it gets, and all that does is insert a union member tag after the stack reference, based on the declared "type" (actually a tag) in the `%type` or `%token` declaration.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that you might not have looked closely enough at my answer. There is a significant difference between `$$ = $1;` and `$$ = 1;` which is possibly clouded by the coincidence over the various uses of `1` in that line.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I understand what you (as well as the bison manual) are saying. But I'm getting a failure on the following simple example: `%union {int val; char num; } %type<num> number number : '1' {$$ = $1}` The error I'm getting is: `error: $1 of ‘number’ has no declared type`. It feels like I'm missing something very simple, which makes me feel pretty dumb :( What am I missing?

Comment: As the error says, you have not declared the typ `'1'`, which you need to do once you introduce `%union` and attempt to use a semantic value. Sorry to repeat myself, but this is explained in the bison manual. But why do you feel you need that union? Please stare at `number : '1' { $$ = 1; }` some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112319/discussion-between-flashburn-and-rici).